# jQuery .hover() on indiviudal <LI>

Tags: jquery, hover, html-lists

I have a close button that I want to show on hovered li elements, but my script targets every li in the list and not just the one that is hovered.

```
$("#sortable li").hover(function () {
$(".close").show();
},

function () {
$(".close").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#sortable li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".close").show();
},

function () {
    $(this).find(".close").hide();
});
```

Comment: Because `$(".close")` returns a collection containing every element in the document that has class `close`, but `$(this).find(".close")` returns only the elements inside the hovered `li` that have class `close`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#sortable li").hover(function() {
  $(".close", this).show();
},
function() {
  $(".close", this).hide();
});
```

Comment: "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $( "span", this ) is equivalent to $( this ).find( "span" )." - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1